# How to define User/Permission relationship as M:M?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, erd

The `Resource` relates to `Action` as **M**:**M** via `Permission` join table/separate entity. User can have many named permissions. The same permission may be assigned to multiple users.

How to define `User`-`Permission` relation as **M**:**M**? How would it look like in **EF**?

**EDIT**

- Should I combine ResourceId and ActionId as a primary key in **EF**?
- How do I associate `Permission` with `User` then?
- How do I make inserts/selects?

Would it be right to map it like that:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Permissions)
    .WithMany(p => p.Users)
    .Map(c => {
        c.MapLeftKey("ResourceId");
        c.MapLeftKey("ActivityId");
        c.ToTable("UserPermissions");
     });
```

provided that `Permission` is defined like so:

```
public class Permission {
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Int32 ResourceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Resource Resource { get; set; }

    public Int32 ActivityId { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

and `User` like so:

```
public class User : Entity {
    public String Username { get; set; }
    public String UserImagePath { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.Username = username;
        this.Password = password;
        this.Permissions = new HashSet<Permission>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can model an EF relation **M:M**, without having to think about the link table that will be needed. There are some nice articles about this on the web, eg. [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a Many-to-Many realationship between  `User` and `Permission` you need to create two navegation properties of type `ICollection<>`:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Resource Resource { get; set; }

    public int ActionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Action Action { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Code First convention will recognize the many-to-many relationship
and build a join table in the database with the appropriate keys of the tables it’s
joining. The keys are both primary keys of the join table and foreign keys pointing to
the joined tables. The name of the new table is created by combining the names of
the classes it’s joining and then pluralizing the result.

If you like do this yourself you can do it using [Fluent Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx). An easy way is overriding the `OnModelCreating` method of your Context. I show below an example how could be in your case:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Name).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Password).IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Permission>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Permission>().Property(u => u.Name).IsRequired();

        //configuring the many-to-many relationship
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Permissions)
            .WithMany(p => p.Users)
            .Map(c => c.ToTable("UserPermissions"));
 }
```

As you can see, you can use Fluent Api not just to specify your relationships. Also, you can specify which properpy would be the Primary Key, if some property would be required, and so on.All this things you can do them as well using [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In order to have many to many relation between User and Permission just add respective collections.
Add collection of Permissions in User and collection of Users in Permission.

Something like

```
User
...
...
<ICollection> Permissions
```

```
Permissions
....
....
<ICollection> Users
```

this will hopefully add a new table like PermissionsUsers or UsersPermissions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got:

**DbContext**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RoleResourceActivity> RoleResourceActivities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>().HasKey(i => i.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Resource>().HasKey(i => i.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(i => i.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<RoleResourceActivity>().HasKey(i => new {
            i.ResourceId, 
            i.ActivityId, 
            i.RoleId
        });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public AppDbContext() : base("AppDb") { 
        Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(new AppDbContextInitializer());
    }
}
```

**Models**

```
public class RoleResourceActivity {
    public Int32 ResourceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Resource Resource { get; set; }

    public Int32 ActivityId { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }

    public Int32 RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class User {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Username { get; set; }
    public String UserImagePath { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public User(String username, String password) : this() {
        this.Username = username;
        this.Password = password;
    }

    protected User() { 
        this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }
}

public class Role {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<RoleResourceActivity> RoleResourceActivities { get; set; }

    public Role(String name) : this() { 
        this.Name = name;
    }

    protected Role() {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
        this.RoleResourceActivities = new HashSet<RoleResourceActivity>();
    }
}

public class Resource {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<RoleResourceActivity> RoleResourceActivities { get; set; }

    public Resource(String name) : this() {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    protected Resource() {
        this.RoleResourceActivities = new HashSet<RoleResourceActivity>();
    }
}

public class Activity {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<RoleResourceActivity> RoleResourceActivities { get; set; }

    public Activity(String name) : this() {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    protected Activity() {
        this.RoleResourceActivities = new HashSet<RoleResourceActivity>();
    }
}
```